# Convert an integer 0-31 into a single character

Tags: python

I want to take the values of the month and day and save them in a shorter format. My current code to convert the integer 1-31 into an integer or letter looks like this:

```
def make_one_char(x):
    list = [
        0, 
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'g',
        'h',
        'i',
        'j',
        'k',
        'l',
        'm',
        'n',
        'o',
        'p',
        'q',
        'r',
        's',
        't',
        'u',
        'v',
        'w',
        'x',
        'y',
        'z'
    ]

    return list[x]

# conver them to single char
file_dates = [file_date.year, make_one_char(file_date.month), make_one_char(file_date.day)]

print(file_dates)
```

It works exactly as expected but I can't help but wonder if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: There are ways to do it using `if` to test whether the number is 0-9 or higher, and then using `chr()` and `ord()` for the higher case. But it's probably not more efficient in terms of machine code. List indexing is very efficient.

Comment: "shorter" format with what constraints and for what purpose?  Does the representation need to be printable?

Comment: Looks like a problem of base conversion. You want to convert a number from base 10 to base 31. And your approach has nothing wrong with it. Just a reminder, never use a reserved function name as a variable name. BTW you can import digits and ASCII letters from `string`,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the function in C which was eventually compiled to a Python Library.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "oneChar.h"

PyObject * oneChar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    int x;
    
    // parses the arguments that have been passed from Python into local variables
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &x)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    char L[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    char s[2] = {L[x], '\0'}; // Create a null-terminated string with a single character

    return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [chr() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to return a character by Unicode codepoint. If you look closely to the [Unicode character list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) you may notice that letters from `a` to `z` are sequential and their start and end codepoints are `97` and `122` correspondingly. So, if we get `x > 10` we should return `chr(97 + x - 10)` and otherwise return the x itself. Here is updated code:

```
def make_one_char(x):
    if 0 <= x < 10:
        return x
    elif 10 <= x <= 35:
        return chr(87 + x)
```

Also please note, in your original code you have used `list` as variable name, please, do not shadow builtin names.